Обработчик отправки данных из HTML формы в MYSQL
У кнопки
<button id="FORM" class="form-button" type="submit">Print</button>

два обработчика
<script>                            
    const element = document.getElementById('FORM');                            
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
        // ...
    });
    
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        setTimeout(function() {location.reload()}); window.print(); return false;
    });
</script>

Сама по себе кнопка отправляет данные в базу без проблем через PHP обработчик. Но если подключить этот скрипт с обработчиком, то данные не отправляются, а только появляется возможность отправки страницы на печать. Какой код вставить в первый обработчик, чтобы перед печатью данные из формы отправлялись в MYSQL? Спасибо.

В этой статье много вариантов https://doka.guide/js/deal-with-forms/
